# codechef problem COVIDLQ wrong anwer error

Tags: c

in https://www.codechef.com/problems/COVIDLQ problem my test cases are giving me correct answer. But after submitting it says wrong answer(WA). Can anyone explain what is wrong in this code.

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int test_case,j,N,x=0,diff=0,yes;
    int *a;
    int *b;
    scanf("%d",&test_case);
    while(test_case-->0)
    {
        scanf("%d",&N);
        a=(int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
        b=(int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        scanf("%d",&a[j]);

            for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            {
                if(a[j]==1)
                {
                    b[x++]=j;
                }
            }
            for(j=0;j<x-1;j++)
            {
                diff=b[j+1]-b[j];
                if(diff>=6)
                yes=1;else yes=0;
            }


            if(yes==1 || x==1)
                printf("YES\n");
                else
                printf("NO\n");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never set `x` back to zero in your loop.